# Does jQuery('#id').length always return 1?

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble figuring out why .length always seems to return 1 when counting elements having the same id in the page. I do know that there should only be elements with unique html id's in an html document, but in the project I am working on, the user may inadvertently add duplicates.

So, is it the normal behaviour for jQuery to always return 1 when counting elements id's?

```
<div id="1">foo</div>
<div id="1">foo</div>

jQuery(function(){
   alert(jQuery('#1').length); // returns 1
});
```

I have built an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eSNZx/

Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems odd that users would be allowed to add multiple elements of the same ID

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eSNZx/1/ for uggly code

Comment: This is a totally valid question! Stop the downvoting!

Comment: Valid, but there's probably a duplicate this should be linked to. I haven't found it yet.

Comment: You're not doing it right -> http://jsfiddle.net/gzsY4/

Comment: Nobody has mentioned it yet but id's cannot start with a number. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: 2019 note: id attributes in HTML5 can now start with a number and still be valid, so the above comment is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Returns 0 or 1. Multiple elements with the same id is not valid.

It's not a jQuery or javascript restriction but HTML one. Check [7.5.2 Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) for official word about that.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is normal. However, you can work around it by using the attribute equals selector.

```
$("[id=1]").length
```

Obviously, having non-unique id's is invalid. Since you are dealing with user input, it is possible to occur if you aren't preventing it.

Alternatively, you can use .children(), .find(), .siblings(), and/or .filter() to get the same effect. Or possibly even a more complex selector, such as `#parent #1`

Answer (score 3):

Because identifiers are intended to be unique, by their very nature; luckily, jQuery handles this gracefully, and perfectly reasonably, in most cases by selecting the first and only one.

You *can* add more than one element with the same id, but it makes nonsense to do so, and such kinds of 'conflicting' behaviour should be quite expected.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, always *at max* one. But it *works* at a (invalid) page where there are multiple elements with the same ID. Avoid that, though, as it may yield unexpected results (see below).

Check [the **jQuery documentation for the `ID Selector (“#id”)`**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> **`ID Selector (“#id”)`**
>         Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.
>         Calling `jQuery()` (or `$()`) with an id selector as its argument will **return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element**.

A note from that very link, explains the behavior for invalid pages:

> Each `id` value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   **will only select the first matched element in the DOM.** This behavior
>   **should not be relied on**, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is **invalid.**

Answer (score 2):

Since IDs should be unique, this is probably the browser doing this, not jQuery. `document.getElementById('1')` will only return zero or one element.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your jQuery selector only returns one element with the id of `1`. This is because ids are supposed to be unique. Try changing id to class as this fiddle shows and select using the jQuery class selector.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eSNZx/

Answer (score 0):

I had that error and I wrote

```
$('div[name=1]').length
```

which solved the issue for me.