# Connecting jquery with php outputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a prob and it is when I echo something from database that contains textarea and some text.
My jquery code work only for one output not all of them.

I tried adding id for each one different and in jquery say

`$("#and_id_for_textarea")`

with php echo

`#blabla<?php echo $status-id; ?>`

But it does not work... Anyone have some explanations?

Comment: Show the code you're really working with

Comment: Please ensure that you are using unique ids. If you have multiple elements with the same id then jQuery will only return the 1st element. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703186/does-jqueryid-length-always-return-1)

Comment: Use common class not ID for repeating elements

Comment: `$status-id;` this throws an error.

Comment: This is my whole question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666301/jquery-takes-last-output-as-value/36666612#36666612

Comment: @charlietfl I tried but it is not working can you give me basic example how to connect some jquery code like onhover at div which was echoed by echoing rows from database.. to show me some text?